# Azure Data Studio does not remember or persist connections

Tags: sql-server, jupyter-notebook, azure-data-studio

Newbie question:

I have a group of notebooks that I'd like to connect to a single server and database in the same ADS session, structured like chapters in a book.  For a single notebook, I can specify and connect to a database, and execute code cells successfully.

When I open another notebook (appears as a new tab within the current ADS window, same folder and workspace), I do not see the connection I defined previously in the "attach to" dropdown list.  I have to go through the connection wizard again to enter the server and authentication details.

Also, the previously defined connection does not show-up under recent or saved connections, even after checking "remember password" when setting up the connection.  Has anyone seen this behaviour before?

I haven't found any documentation on managing multiple notebooks.  Am I going beyond how notebooks are supposed to be used?

Thanks.

```
Version: 1.21.0 (system setup)
Commit: 2413919f186f780f0193d047da3d90bb3c1e9bf6
Date: 2020-08-11T20:52:47.502Z
VS Code: 1.48.0
Electron: 7.3.2
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19041
```

Comment: Just discovered that if you go through the "Add connection" wizard the named connection is saved.  However, it still does not show-up in the "Attach to" dropdown list:  You have to select "change selection" to find and select the saved connection.  You also still have to change/select the connection in EACH notebook.

Comment: it ain't a newbie question at all... it might just be microsoft not explicitly specifying that this feature only works if and when [insert a bunch of useless conditions here]...

I'm facing the same issue... on OSX

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting within the File-->Preferences-->Settings called "Notebook: Save Connection Name". *(You can search settings for that name)* Once that is toggled, the notebook will remember the connection name that you used.

This assumes that you have saved and named connections in the first place.